# OpenAPI security scope for certain query parameters

Tags: openapi

I have a use case that I need to check the authorization based on a query parameter.

I have an `/products` endpoint for fetching the list of products. But the products have `reviewStatus` and end users are only allowed to fetch products that `reviewStatus` is `approved`. But admin can fetch every product. Based on this requirements, I came up with the below API design.

```
/products?reviewStatus=[REVIEW_STATUS]
```

if `REVIEW_STATUS` is set to `waiting` or `rejected`, and the client who makes the request doesn't have permission to read those products, then the server should return the `401 Unauthorized` response.

But it seems writing an OpenAPI specification for these requirements isn't possible. I couldn't set `security` for each query parameter.

How do I resolve it? Is there a better API design for this?